# How to make a table on Access using "Count" and Age Range?

Tags: ms-access

I downloaded a record of all the people on the first fleet from this website. http://firstfleet.uow.edu.au/download.html
I downloaded the Excel and imported it into Access. In the document, certain people’s age is not known so they are simply put as -1.

I am trying to make this table but I am struggling.
[image]

I’ve tried doing it by creating a table but that was too hard so I decided to create a query instead.  I am using “Crosstab” but failing to use it successfully.

When I do try to sub the -1 for unknown:

[image]

Messages like this pop up:

[image]

How do we add the table in but sub the -1 for unknown while keeping the layout the same? I am hard stuck at a place where I cannot even view how my query looks.

How do I even make the layout the same as the picture shown above?

**UPDATE:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the age groups with Switch() function and use that calculated field for CROSSTAB RowColumn. I renamed the Age field in table from the original import name to shorten the expression.

```
TRANSFORM Count(Convicts.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Switch([Age]=-1,"Unknown",[Age]<15,"10-14",[Age]<20,"15-19",[Age]<25,"20-24",[Age]<30,"25-29",[Age]<35,"30-34",[Age]<40,"35-39",[Age]<45,"40-44",[Age]<50,"45-49",[Age]<60,"50-59",[Age]<100,"60-99") AS AgeGrp
FROM Convicts
GROUP BY Switch([Age]=-1,"Unknown",[Age]<15,"10-14",[Age]<20,"15-19",[Age]<25,"20-24",[Age]<30,"25-29",[Age]<35,"30-34",[Age]<40,"35-39",[Age]<45,"40-44",[Age]<50,"45-49",[Age]<60,"50-59",[Age]<100,"60-99")
PIVOT Convicts.Gender;
```

[image]
The total row is added by clicking the Sigma(Totals) icon on the ribbon when query is in Datasheet view.

A simpler calculation will generate more groups:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Convicts.ID) AS CountOfID
SELECT Partition([Age],0,100,5) AS AgeGrp
FROM Convicts
GROUP BY Partition([Age],0,100,5)
PIVOT Convicts.Gender;
```

But a little adjustment to the SELECT clause will get same output as the first:
`SELECT IIf([Age]=-1,"Unknown",IIf([Age]<50,Partition([Age],0,50,5),IIf([Age]<60,"50:59","60:99"))) AS AgeGrp`

Could add a field in table and use one of those expressions in UPDATE action SQL to add calculated AgeGrp, which would simplify the CROSSTAB and other queries needing that group identifier.

Comment: Thank you :) Will check if this works later this week.

Comment: It keeps saying that the Microsoft database engine does not recognize [Age] as a valid expression. How to fix this?

Comment: The answer is marked as accepted. Surely that means you had success? I downloaded the data, changed field name, queries worked for me.

Comment: Marked as accepted too early. Sorry. Which field names did you change and to what? Also, what does it mean by 'pivot'? It's not possible to enter what you inserted into 'Group By' as messages keep popping up and where is 'insert'?

Comment: [Age] field had a different name in the download. It is the field that has the individual age data. That's is the only field name I changed. Are you saying the Switch() or Partition() functions don't work? All of the query versions suggested worked for me. Why do you want 'insert'?

Comment: I've added two new pictures into the original question. The first picture shows what is popping up and the second one shows what I am doing. Could you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Copy/paste my SQL statement into SQLView of query builder and simply change [Age] to [Age leaving england] in the statement.

Comment: Everything worked fine but I can't actually pres the total button. How do i fix this?